# Have a search command on discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py

would like to know if it's possible to add a search command to my discord bot, I will basically use the command to find files inside a directory. For example there is a file named name.txt, and I could do `/search nam` and it would search for this file and output the name of similar files in the directory.

Comment: Directory on the server?

Comment: Directory in the host, my bot is hosted on a raspberry pi, so the search command would search through a directory on the rpi, not the discord server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's simple, just import `listdir` from `os` module and give folder path to `listdir` function then add one parameter in the command which will be used to match the files in the given path.

Try following code:

```
@bot.command()
async def search(ctx, file_name):
    search_result = 'Search Results:'
    from os import listdir
    for file in listdir('data'):
        if file_name in file.lower():
            search_result = search_result+'\n'+file
    if search_result == 'Search Results:':
        await ctx.send('Error: Not matched with any file.')
    else:
        await ctx.send(search_result)
```

Comment: Thanks! Worked like I wanted. Also wanted to know if it's possible to add this code inside an already existing command, I have a get command that gets a certain file and output a link to it, is it possible to output the search results when the argument (the file you want to get) is incorrect, like that :
`#get file`
File not found but similar files found:
`file results`

Comment: NVM, actually found a way to do this by adding:
`if get(commands.CommandNotFound):
            await ctx.send("file not found, here are similar names:")
            search_result = 'Search Results:'
            for file in listdir('directory/....'):
                if arg in file.lower():
                    search_result = search_result+'\n'+file
            if search_result == 'Search Results:':
                await ctx.send('Error: Not matched with any file.')
            else:
                await ctx.send(search_result)`